# What's the point of ordinal numbers, in particular, large ordinals?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I have searched on line trying to find the point of ordinal numbers, and even though I can find many sites defining them and explaining their properties, none of them goes beyond the basic reason for their existance, as:

> Ordinal numbers are the "labels" needed to arrange collections of objects
> in order. An ordinal number is used to describe the order type of a
> well-ordered set

Or something similar. But why does it feel like they are trying to see how "big" they can go, as in defining, $\omega2 $ , $\omega^2$, $\omega^\omega$, $\omega^{\omega^\omega}$, $\varepsilon_0$,$\varepsilon_\varepsilon$,$\omega_1$, etc but without pointing at any application of these large numbers.

Is there a real application, even if it's only to support other areas of mathematics, or is it just a display of big numbers ? Isn't $\omega_1$ big enough for everything we know ?

Comment: proof theory$ $?

Comment: @AnginaSeng For the most part proof theory lives well below $\omega_1$ - indeed, below $\omega_1^{CK}$.

Comment: $|\wp(\Bbb R)|>\omega_1$.

Comment: A good starting point is to first consider **cardinals** (or **initial ordinals**) bigger than $\omega_1$ which show up in mathematics - for example, the cardinality of the set of all sets of real numbers, as Brian Scott mentioned. Ordinals are generally harder to think about than cardinals, at least at first.

Comment: well, I know the cardinality of the power set of X is larger than the cardinality of X, but that wasn't my question. I still can see the point of large cardinal numbers. But my question is about large ordinal numbers, larger than $\omega_1$, where I can't see any application

Comment: You can use them to prove Goodstein's Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem), showing that the hydra game terminates, eventually. :-)

Comment: The analogous question would be: there are just „big“ natural numbers: googolplex, Graham‘s number, numbers larger than these, what on the world should they be useful for? While they do have applications (as larger ordinals do), the right answer should be that they simply come out nicely if one develops the theory in a certain correct way and vice versa they are also needed for such a theory.

Comment: @Qi Zhu However, as far as I know there aren't university courses dedicated to large natural natural numbers. Large ordinal numbers, seem to be taught in every set theory course, though.

Comment: @KazOrdoon: Cardinal numbers **are** ordinal numbers. Specifically, they are initial ordinals, as Noah Schweber already mentioned.

Comment: @KazOrdoon: Ordinal numbers are taught in every set theory course, and some of them are large. Arbitrarily ignoring the ordinals larger than some particular $\alpha$ would be like arbitrarily ignoring all positive integers larger than some particular $n$: unnatural, and not just pointless, but actively problematic, since it would make the theory more complicated for no good reason.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott This is what I don't get.  We could, in order not to arbitrarily ignore any particular large natural number, start writing down the highest natural number that we can imagine, but what's the point ? We know we can always add +1. Similar with ordinals. But then again, I'm not asking to ignore these large ordinals, but my original question was where are they used: Is it just: nowhere, we just want to see how high we can go. Or is it: Yes, we really need these ordinals to solve this particular problem.

Comment: @KazOrdoon: I have never seen (or taught) any use of ordinals that was not either part of the general development of set theory or a specific application, so I really don’t know to what kinds of things you’re objecting.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott  Thanks, this is I was looking for. I would really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction for some of these applications for large ordinals $\geq \omega_1$

Comment: @KazOrdoon: The first example of a [Dowker space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dowker_space) in $\sf{ZFC}$, constructed by my *Doktormutter* about $50$ years ago and announced [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183532748), uses all of the ordinals less than $\omega_\omega$.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Great! Thanks for the link

Comment: @KazOrdoon: You’re welcome.

Comment: Regarding your answer to me, a course in set theory isn't about large ordinals either, those are just generic examples of ordinal numbers - i.e. what do typical examples of ordinals look like.

Comment: (I don't get why people are downvoting btw, this isn't a particularly bad question.)

Comment: For me the best comment is from Professor Vector since it could be proven that the peano axioms cannot prove that every Goodstein sequence terminates. Here we actually need the ordinal numbers.

Comment: $\omega_1$ has so many applications when teaching topology. It is a goldmine of examples.

Comment: @QiZhu Asking what the point of $\varepsilon_0$ is, followed by asking if $\omega_1$ isn't big enough already may be part of the problem.

Comment: Transfinite inductions of length $\omega_1$ are not uncommon in real analysis. They show up when studying Cantor-Bendixson derivatives and in many other instances. Countable ordinals much larger than $\varepsilon_0$ are common in the study of the proof-theoretic strength of various formal theories.